# Definitions of subtraction and division

Tags: real-numbers

I'm reading some lecture notes, but I don't understand their definitions of subtraction  and division.

It states that subtraction is the inverse operation of addition, which I believe, but states that $a - b = c$ means that $a = b + c$. Similarly, it says that division is the inverse operation of multiplication, so $\frac{a}{b} = c$ means that $a = b \cdot c$.

Both of these seem to be "consequences" of subtraction and division to mean. I'd be inclined to define $a - b = a + (-b)$ and division by $\frac{a}{b} = a \cdot b^{-1}$. I don't understand why these definitions are intuitive or natural. Could someone explain?

Comment: If you define $a-b$ as $a+(-b)$, you have to define what the symbol $(-b)$ means.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ok, that makes sense. Is the only idea that $a = b + c$ is true if and only if $a - b = c$, and it allows us to "define" subtraction in terms of things we already know? (And similarly for division.)

Comment: @Cardinality No. (-b) and $b^{-1}$ are defined in the field axioms. Then we can write a-b=a+(-b) and $\frac ab$=a $b^{-1}$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator These are the definitions I'm accustomed to. I'm just trying to understand the definition in these notes, which is different from those definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd be inclined to define $a - b = a + (-b)$ and division by $\frac{a}{b} = a \cdot b^{-1}$.

That's still not the full story, but a reasonable step.  What you still have to do is to define what $-b$. Is supposed to mean.

As the context is presumably some field $(K,+,\,\cdot\,)$, this means that $(K,+)$ is an abelian (=commutative) group.  This means that every element $b\in K$ has an inverse, denoted as "$-b$". Now the existence of unique, inverse elements and associativity means that a cancelling rule holds.  This means that $$a+b=c\quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad a=c+(-b)\tag 1$$ for all $a$, $b$, $c$ in the group.  That is, one can "undo" additions. Here, "$-b$" is just the symbol for the inverse of $b$ in the group, that is the unique element associated to $b$ that satisfies $$b+(-b) = (-b)+b = 0\tag 2$$ where "$0$" denotes the neutral element of $(K,+)$.

Whether one preferes $(1)$ or $(2)$ is a matter of taste; the group and field axioms usually use $(2)$, whereas the formulation $(1)$ is more useful for manipulating equations.

The case for multiplication is similar with two exceptions:

- It's only that $(K\!\setminus\!\{0\},\,\cdot\,)$ is a group, i.e. $0$ has no multiplicative inverse and one cannot undo multiplications with 0.
- Multiplication need not be commutative.  An example of such a skew-field is Hamilton's quaternions.

If the latter is the case, one must be more careful, though.  For example, one should avoid notations like $\frac ab$ because in the skew case, one usually has $a\cdot(b^{-1})\neq (b^{-1})\cdot a$.  "$b^{-1}$" is one common notation for the inverse of $b$ if the group notation is as a multiplicative group.  A different notation can be "$1/b$" where "1" is the neutral element in that group.  This notation works and is unique because $1\cdot (b^{-1}) = (b^{-1})\cdot 1 = b^{-1}$ even if multiplication is not commutative.

---